# MySQL memory is keep on increasing , any reason?

Tags: mysql, performance, performance-tuning

On one of our production host MySQL memory is keep on increasing day-by-day.
I tried reboot of MySQL instance but still no avail.

System has 16Gb of RAM.

**TOP output**

```
top - 13:05:13 up 35 days,  1:39,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.00
Tasks: 101 total,   1 running, 100 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.8%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16436176k total, 13097948k used,  3338228k free,   233236k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,    33928k used,  4160368k free,  5540804k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                          
19548 mysql     15   0 13.9g 6.7g 6800 S  0.0 42.8  35:56.54 mysqld
```

**MySQL configuration**

```
max_allowed_packet                      = 128M
max_connections                         = 500
thread_cache_size                       = 100
open_files_limit                        = 15000
table_open_cache                        = 3000
tmp_table_size                          = 64M
max_heap_table_size                     = 64M
read_buffer_size                        = 512K
read_rnd_buffer_size                    = 512K
sort_buffer_size                        = 1M
key_buffer_size                         = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size                 = 128M
bulk_insert_buffer_size                 = 64M
```

Comment: I tried to put your values to http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/ and it seems like 1.5GB top, but you do not mention innodb_buffer_pool and some other values.